# How can I 'trim' a path in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say I have a container. I want to surround it with a border (or anything that would outline it) and be able to change it's start and end points. This would be similar to the trim paths effect in Adobe After effects. I've looked up options for container borders but the best I could find was to add it to juts one side and that is not the look I want.

The best way I can describe what I want to do is to have a border or outline to the container that looks sort of like a circular progress (but isn't round and takes the shape of the container) that has the start and end points move.

Here is a quick example I made in After Effects of what I am looking for: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DgHZbLv_TX1D_lpfYJlL4QA0kOVbQZDe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: write a custom [Decoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Decoration-class.html) class - some working example is `CornerDecorationTest` [here](https://gist.github.com/pskink/da43c327b75eec05d903fa1b4d0c4d3e#file-decorations-dart-L7)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll take a look and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to be done through CustomPainters. Here is a repo I came across which does this through custom painters https://github.com/divyanshub024/flutter_path_animation.